# Overriding abstract type members

Tags: scala, generics

```
abstract class Box {
    type T <: String
}

type InvariantBox = Box { type T = AnyRef } // compiles

abstract class Box2 extends Box {
    type T = AnyRef //Error:overriding type T in class
                    // Box with bounds <: String; type T 
                    // has incompatible type type T = AnyRef
}
```

Why is it possible to redefine `T` type parameter in InvariantBox but not allowed to do the same in `Box2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the right to create intersection

```
type HasT = { type T = AnyRef }
type InvariantBox = Box with HasT
```

Otherwise not for any types `A`, `B` you could create type `A with B`.

And for classes there are overriding rules.

Scala allows defining types without any values or with only `null` value.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Could you give an example of creating type with null value?

Comment: By type with null value I meant `val x: InvariantBox = null`. No other `val x: InvariantBox = new Box { type T ... }` compiles.

Comment: [Compound types](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#compound-types) in Scala specification, [intersection types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/intersection-types.html) in Dotty.